# Not willing to pay for a course

Tags: graduate-admissions

Hi please tell me if i'm wrong here, I started a course a few years ago, may be 2.

It was an accountancy course, the ACCA. I left the course after 3 lessons out of 10 as the tutor who was supposed to do the course left on maternity leave and was replaced with a foreign (European) tutor who spoke broken English and all she did was try to make small talk jokes. Now I left the course and explained that this wasn't something that I signed up for and now they want £2300 of me. but I'm refusing to pay. Am I right or wrong and if someone can point me in the correct direction on how to proceed.

Comment: I presume you weren't told of the substitution in advance, nor of the lack of qualifications of the replacement. It really isn't fair to bait-and-switch like that.

Comment: I think you should pay because you signed up for it. However, you do have the right to file a complaint to the school and tell them you want the money back or re-take the course for free.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the context here; it might be helpful to know if this course is through a college or a tutoring company or some other entity. Also, is the option available (and acceptable to you) to pay and take the current version of the course?

Answer (score 4):

This seems less like an academic question than a question of contract law.  Nevertheless, for what it's worth, if you are refusing to pay the amount claimed, then presumably the onus will be on the education-provider to sue you for the money, and establish in court that it is a valid debt.  You will have an opportunity to argue that they failed to provide you with the contracted service and that the substituted service was sub-standard.  Whether or not you have a good case will depend on the details of the matter, the specifics of your agreement with the provider, and the commercial laws of the jurisdiction in which this occurred.

If necessary and affordable, you should seek legal advice (from real commercial lawyers - not random guys on academia.SE).

Comment: UK common law may proceed differently than US law.

Comment: Absolutely - and even within these countries there is not a uniform commercial law (e.g., within the US there are different state laws).  These days most countries have extensive legislation that modifies the common law position, and this generally has some minor differences by jurisdiction.  We would need to know the exact jurisdiction to know what laws apply.